# Hilbert Transform and the Time-frequency spectrum in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, spectrogram, hilbert-curve

I need to understand the difference between the two commands `hht` and `hilbert` of Matlab to implement the Hilbert transform.

Are the results similar when we have real-valued data?

Also for the implementation of time-frequency spectrum of Hilbert's instantaneous frequencies and amplitudes, what methods are available other than spectrogram (its STFT based).